# Cat flap in window into neighbours garden?

Tags: cats

We are moving into a ground floor (street level) flat. We have a cat flap that fits into sash windows. We could either let the cats through our door into the shared stairwell and then onto the street, or let them through the windows overlooking the nighbour's garden which is a level below our flat but there are ways for the cats to climb back up (namely, a rooftop). I'm sure if they went out the front they would find their way into the garden at the back anyway.

I'm planning on asking the neighbour if it's okay to put the cat flap there (I mean, we could equally as well just open the window, and who can blame us for opening our own window?). But if they say no to the cat flap, they might get cross at the cats going out of an open window.

We do have windows out the front, which is a quiet street, but they are overlooking a `moat' as you might call it, which is too deep for the cats to jump up from. The cats would possibly be able to jump across the moat from the street, if it wasn't that there is a wrought-iron fence. It hasn't even got gaps in at the bottom: there is a kind of metal plate rising up about a foot.

We could manually let them out through the shared stairwell, but it might lead to a lot of meowing and scratching at the door which is not good in a rented property.

Hopefully the description is clear enough. Just asking for advice on (preferably convenient) methods of allowing them out.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at our related posts on [Cats ands Gardens](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcats%5D+garden) A neighbor without cats may prefer you don't let your cat into their garden.

As you suggest in your question, talking to the neighbor is a good first step.

If you are new to the area, you will want to check on local laws and how they are applied to outdoor cats.